# jQuery access data-url element and check with url parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

First of all; I'm sorry if my quesiton is irrelevant, because i'm newbie on `jQuery`

I have a menu in my website. Here is HTML;

```
<ul class="page-sidebar-menu">
    <li data-link="index.php"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li data-link="logout.php"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm taking url path to compare with `li data-link` to add `active` class to `li`

But unfortunately it's returning undefined.

Here is my javascript / jQuery;

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname; // Returns path only
var encPath  = encodeURIComponent(pathname);  // Encoded URL
var splPath  = encPath.split('%2F');
var cleanUrl = splPath.pop(); // Clean Url
var dataUrl  = $('ul.page-sidebar-menu > li').attr('data-link');
$(dataUrl).each(function( i ) {
    if(dataUrl === cleanUrl) {
        dataUrl.addClass('active');
    }
});
```

So what's wrong with my code? How can i fix it?
Any help greatly appricated.

PS: Sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$().data('link')` to retrieve the value of `data-link` attribute :

```
$('ul.page-sidebar-menu > li')
  .filter((index, item) => $(item).data('link') === cleanUrl)
  .addClass('active')
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to iterate `$('ul.page-sidebar-menu > li')` and test each elements `data-url` attribute.

```
$('ul.page-sidebar-menu > li').each(function( i ) {
    if($(this).attr('data-link') === cleanUrl) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

You can also use [`Element.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property to access all the custom data attributes `(data-*)` set on element like  `this.dataset.link`

---

Code can be improved as

```
$('ul.page-sidebar-menu > li').filter(function( i ) {
    return this.dataset.link === cleanUrl;            
}).addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `each` on `li` to get `data-link` of each li and match with `cleanUrl`

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname; // Returns path only
var encPath = encodeURIComponent(pathname);  // Encoded URL
var splPath = encPath.split('%2F');
var cleanUrl = splPath.pop(); // Clean Url
$('ul.page-sidebar-menu > li').each(function(){
if ($(this).attr("data-link") === cleanUrl) {
    dataUrl.addClass('active');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> So what's wrong with my code? How can i fix it? Any help greatly appricated.

**Problem:** is with this line of code `$('ul.page-sidebar-menu > li').attr('data-link');` And later you are trying to loop it. The issue is even though this syntax `$('ul.page-sidebar-menu > li')` returns you array of matched elements once you use `.attr` on it it will return you only the value of first element in the array. Hence you are ending up with only one iteration.

**Solution:** As already other answers have stated, Loop your `$('ul.page-sidebar-menu > li')` and then play with the `$(this).data('link')`

```
$('ul.page-sidebar-menu > li').each(function( i ) {
    if($(this).data('link') === cleanUrl) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        return false;   // break loop as we found the link.
    }
});
```

Comment: `$(this).data('link')` will unnecessarily populate the internal cache,  better to use `$(this).attr('data-link')` or `this.dataset.link`

Comment: @Satpal oh.. But I thought using `.data` was the best way.. Thanks for the info..